# Array for errors in sinatra

Tags: ruby, arrays, error-handling, sinatra

To manage errors in my address book app i initialize an array like this

```
err = Array.new
```

and then when i post something it checks if there are empty fields. If yes, for each empty field it adds a record in the array, and then redirect to /add page, like this

```
post '/' do
if params[:fname] == ""
    err.push "Insert a valid first name"
end
if params[:lname] == ""
    err.push "insert a valid last name"
end
if params[:phone] == ""
    err.push "insert a valid phone number"
end
if params[:mail] == ""
    err.push "insert a valid e-mail address"
end
if err.empty?
    c = Contatto.new
    c.fname = params[:fname]
    c.lname = params[:lname]
    c.phone = params[:phone]
    c.mail = params[:mail]
    c.save
    redirect '/'
else
    redirect '/add'
end
end
```

then the add page reads if the array has any record and if yes, cycles it to print each message

```
get '/add' do
  @err = err
  @title = 'Aggiungi'
  erb :aggiungi
end



<% if @err.any? %>
<div class="error">
    <% @err.each do |err| %>
        <%= err %><br>
    <% end %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

i think the error is that it re-initialize the array every time it changes from post '/' to get '/add' and so the result is an empty array...
How can i solve? thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want data for a specific visitor to persist between requests you need to be storing the error array in either a session or a cookie (session probably makes the most sense).

Luckily sessions in Sinatra are pretty easy: http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Using%20Sessions . Once enabled you can put pretty much anything you want into the session hash, so initializing with `session[:errors] = []` and pushing with `session[:errors] << "An error"` should give you the persistence you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you a lot!and how do I clear the session after the form is submitted the second time?

Comment: `session.clear` or `session[:errors].clear` should work, depending on if you want to clear all session data or just the errors.

Comment: I put
    use Rack::Session::Pool
    session[:error] = []
But it's not working, i getNameError: undefined local variable or method `session' for main:Object

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a local variable and expecting it to persist between requests. How is this supposed to happen? Sinatra is not psychic, it will only remember what you tell it to remember, and that's usually done through some kind of database or a client-side cookie.

Generally you should render a response page on failure, making use of the errors you've collected, or redirect on success, where the empty errors array is not relevant.

As a matter of style, the more Ruby way to do things like this is:

```
err = [ ] # Equivalent to Array.new

err << "Example error" # Equivalent to err.push
```

Comment: And there isn't a way to create in a request a global variable?

Comment: There is no such thing as a global variable in Sinatra. Web frameworks do not work like persistent desktop applications or long-running scripts. You must save it into the session or the database for it to be carried from one request to another Carl Zulauf's answer is more specific than mine in this regard.

Comment: Remember that there is no guarantee that the same process will be servicing every request, and it's best to never assume this to be the case. Each requests starts with a blank slate if you're doing things correctly as there is no state preserved in the server process, only in external storage like the session or the database.